# SFML 2.5.1, C++, при нажатии клавиши не срабатывает условие

Tags: c++, sfml

Музыка работает, при нажатии W условие не срабатывает, функция Game_Start не работает и в консоль "lalalla" не выводится, код ниже, понять что не так не получилось :(

```
int main()
    {
        sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(), "S", sf::Style::Fullscreen);

        sf::Music music;
        music.openFromFile("asset/main/music/main.ogg");
        music.play();


        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W))
        {
            music.stop();
            std::cout << "lalalla\n";
            Game_Start();
        }
```

Comment: Ниже идёт просто стандартный цикл sfml

Comment: А он и не срабатывает, нужно обрабатывать ввод в цикле.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(), "S", sf::Style::Fullscreen);
    sf::Event ev;

    sf::Music music;
    music.openFromFile("asset/main/music/main.ogg");
    music.play();

    while(window.isOpen())
    {
         while(window.pollEvent(ev)
         {
             if(ev.type == sf::Event::Closed) window.close();
         }
         if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W))
         {
            music.stop();
            std::cout << "lalalla\n";
            Game_Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, а можно сделать так, чтобы на нажатие лишь 1 раз реагировало? То я жму на W и он каждый раз выполняет

Comment: вроде да, но вот это `sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W)` не подходит, посмотри в доках отслежка нажатий